# Can subtypes of Spark's UserDefinedAggregateFunction be a singleton?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can subtypes of Spark's `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` be a singleton/`object` or must they be a `class` and instantiated on use? The `update`, `merge`, etc calls all take the `MutableAggregationBuffer` as a parameters, so I can't see a reason not to use a singleton.
Is that correct/safe to do?

Ex:

```
object MyUdaf extends org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  // ...
}


someDf.groupBy("foo").agg(MyUdaf(col("bar")).as("bar_aggregated")).show()
```

Comment: @Phillip M, Yes it is possible unless you process on multiple executors on the same JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been working fine for us for some time now, so Ramesh's comment above seems correct.